# forbidden access on wamp server through wlan ip

Tags: wamp

I can't access my server through my wlan ip 192.168.1.4.

My httpd.conf file has a line:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin">
eAllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at this section of your `httpd.conf` file.

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

Now add either a specific ip that you want to allow like this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1.200
```

Or allow access from any ip in the 192.168.1 subnet like this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```